# Markers not working in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm new to Google Maps API. I wrote a program that will put markers on all the points according to their latitude and longitude given in where.js .
It loads the map but no markers are being placed. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

The HTML code is as follows-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Markets of Kolkata</title>
<link href="http://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="where.js"></script>
  <script>

  function initialize() {
    //alert("To see the title of a marker, hover over the marker but don't click.");
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.39961,88.101350)
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 3,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    i = 0;
    var markers = [];
    for ( pos in myData ) {
        i = i + 1;
        var row = myData[pos];
        window.console && console.log(row);
        // if ( i < 3 ) { alert(row); }
        var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(row[0], row[1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: newLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: row[3]
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }
  }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px"></div>
<p>
<b>Developed By </b> 
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/arnab-chakravarty-8a329111b?
trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile"><b>Arnab Chakravarty</b></a>.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript file for 'where.js'-

```
myData = [
[22.5193768,88.3656851, 'K.M.C. Market, 3rd Floor Market Complex, 212, Rash Behari Avenue Road, Hindustan Park, Gariahat, Kolkata, West Bengal 700019, India','COLLEGE STREET MARKET(SPORTS GOOD)'],
[22.4977887,88.3796042, 'Garfa Main Rd, Kolkata, West Bengal 700075, India','COLLEGE STREET MARKET'],
[22.5048463,88.3882325, 'Purbachal Main Rd, Ramlal Bazar, Haltu, Kolkata, West Bengal 700078, India','COLLEGE STREET MARKET'],
[22.5867867,88.3564619, 'Kolkata, West Bengal 700073, India', 'BAITHAK KHANA PAPER MARKET'],
[22.5867867,88.3564619, 'Kolkata, West Bengal 700073, India', 'SAKUNTALA PARK VEGETABLE MARKET'],
[22.5867867,88.3564619, 'Kolkata, West Bengal 700073, India', 'SANTOSHPUR MUNICIPAL MARKET']];
```

Comment: how do you call `initialize` function? do you get any errors in your browsers **developer** tools console? where is the div with the id? Some of your code works - https://jsfiddle.net/Luwpmunp/ - but there are errors

Comment: Here is the full HTML code.@JaromandaX

Comment: yeah, still `http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com` 404 error - so, not much faith in the rest of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript arrays are zero-indexed.  Your code is referring to them as if they were one-indexed.

i.e. your code:

```
i = 0;
var markers = [];
for ( pos in myData ) {
    i = i + 1;
    var row = myData[pos];
    ...
}
```

You're referring to `myData[1]` (the 2nd item), `myData[2]` (the 3rd item), etc, up to and including `myData[6]`. Which would be the 7th item in your array of markers, except you've only got 6 items.  So you're probably getting a JS error (check your console), preventing the markers from loading at all.

Just put the `i = i + 1;` line at the **end** of your loop.  Or change the loop style, e.g.

```
for (var pos = 0; pos < myData.length; pos++) {
    var row = myData[pos];
    window.console && console.log(row);
    var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(row[0], row[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: row[3]
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Comment: In fact you're really treating `myData` as if it were an object, when it's really a 2D array

Comment: Putting the `i = i + 1;` at the end of the line worked and the markers are placed. But title of the markers are not showing when I hover over the marker.

Comment: @ArnabC Change `title: row[3]` to `title: row[2]`

Comment: But I want the fourth item to be the title of the marker. Why is it not taking row[3] as a marker ?

Comment: Nevermind. It's solved. Thanks for your help Duncan .

Answer (score 0):

Correct this line :
 // add this line in  for loop:
  markers.setMap(map);
  markers.push(marker);

And also check this Link : It doesn't open 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js

check console.log if any error : happy to help you